# Consulta sobre bases de datos (diagrama)

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes hermosa comunidad, el día de hoy vengo a plantear una duda que quiero hacerla de la mejor forma posible (Best Practices) en MYSQL.

Resulta que tengo un formulario donde se va a realizar un pedido en el cual se carga el "producto" seleccionado con todos sus extras.

Luego cuando el cliente selecciona, el va a seleccionar varios checkbox de ingredientes. Entonces la idea es guardar cada ingrediente con su precio en una tabla "ingredientes", y mi idea era a medida que la persona va seleccionando los checks hacer un array con las id de cada ingrediente.

La consulta es, en la base de datos, guardo el array con las id`s de los ingredientes en la columna "ingredientes" de mi pedido? o hay alguna forma mejor de hacerlo?

La pregunta mas concretamente sería.

Tabla ingredientes:
(ID, Nombre, Precio)

Tabla pedidos:
(ID, producto, ingredientes)

La pregunta es si esta bien que los ingredientes los guarde siendo un json con los ids de ingredientes para luego hacer un innerjoin a ingredientes.

Comment: en un solo registro quieres guardar todo el array?

Comment: Me parece que sería conveniente poner más contexto en tu pregunta. De entrada, pareciera que debes identificar tus entidades de negocio y establecer la relación entre ellas ¿Un Pedido puede tener varios Productos y a su vez cad Producto incluir varios Ingredientes? Con eso puedes iniciar el diseño de tu modelo de Datos, que eventualmente implementarás en MySQL (o cualquier otra BD Relacional). Ahora bien, no debes guardar arrays en columnas ya que pierdes (o complicas) la explotación posterior de la información.

Answer (score -1):

Veo que en tu modelo tienes una relación muchos a muchos (un pedido puede tener varios ingredientes y cada ingrediente puede estar en múltiples pedidos). Este tipo de relaciones deben eliminarse del modelo.

Para lograr lo anterior, deberías generar una tabla auxiliar (Items) en la que manejas la relación Pedido - Ingredientes. 
El modelo quedaría más o menos así...

Tabla **ingredientes**: (IDIngrediente, Nombre, Precio)

Tabla **pedidos**: (IDPedido, producto)

Tabla **itemsPedido** (IDPedido, IDIngrediente, ... ) En esta tabla, almacenarás un registro para cada ingrediente asociado al pedido. Esto permitirá que mediante queries del mismo motor de BD puedas recuperar de manera simple la información. No debes olvidar establecer las Foreign Keys a las tablas relacionadas.

Esta tabla probablemente también debería incluir campos adicionales como Precio de Venta, Cantidad Vendida, etc.

Me parece que también debería haber una tabla de Productos, con su correspondiente relación con la tabla de Pedidos.

Espero la información te sea de utilidad.